# Resource in src folder not included in Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

I am generating a Runnable Jar file using Eclipse. But when I am testing it out, it gives me an unsatisfied link error. This is because it is missing a resource, but this resource is located in the src folder. Wich is obviously added to the Java build path. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
    final URL geoDBFileURL = GeoIPServiceImpl.class.getResource("GeoIP.dat");
    if (geoDBFileURL == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No default GeoIP dat
abase file found
        at oast.geoip.GeoIPServiceImpl.<init>(GeoIPServiceImpl.java:20)
        at oast.Oast.initialize(Oast.java:409)
        at oast.Oast.main(Oast.java:434)
```

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace

Comment: Flagged as very low quality: Please give more info about your problem.

Comment: Addressing resources can go bad any number of ways. Can you post the code and error message?

Comment: Edited the question with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put it in the resources folder instead of the src folder, here is a similar problem: [How to export jar with images on Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881123/how-to-export-jar-with-images-on-eclipse)