# Problems exporting, File not loading from project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

What's going on is that I have my images and `.wav` files in a a project folder and it's running fine in eclipse, however once I export it into a executable jar file it stops loading images. I've tried Extracting libraries into jar file and I've tried packaging them in a jar file. What do I do? I'm panicking because I need to get this ready by tomorrow! I know I have the path right, it's starts the code, but stops after a little.

I get this error:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
   Exported with compile warnings:
AdventureQuestv4.0.2/src/adventureQuestv/AdventureQuestMain.java
```

Here's the code I use to load an image

```
URL GiantT2 =  AdventureQuestBetaMain.class.getResource("GiantT.png");
    giantT = ImageIO.read(GiantT2);
```

I know the images are in the file, it's just that they're not loading.

Comment: Try putting the images and .wave files in the folder containing the executable jar file

Comment: " I've tried Extracting libraries into jar file and I've tried packaging them in a jar file", Please tell which all libraries and how have you done the packaging

Comment: I go export-java-Runnable Jar File-Extract Required Libraries into generated JAR-

Comment: I go export-java-Runnable Jar File-Package Required Libraries into generated JAR also

Comment: The error have you shown is during generation of jar file is a warning, What is the error you get when you execute the jar file... Use a log to get that error, that would only indicate where the things are going wrong

Answer (score 0):

check out this post.May be you are also having the same issue.

[How to export jar with images on Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881123/how-to-export-jar-with-images-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Use [fat jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fjep/) eclipse plugin. Select all resources like .wav and image files etc while exporting.

Before exporting resolve all Java compiler errors and warnings(to the maximum extent).

Answer (score 0):

While exporting the jar file with images in your eclipse ,

You must check these in the Jar Export dialog box,

1.Export generated class files and resources

2.Export Java source file and resources

Options:

- Compress the content of the jar file
- Add directory entries

Answer (score 0):

please delete the existing workspace and reimport the source code
i hope this may resolve issue

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30911377)